# Doxygen duplicates member group if in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, documentation, doxygen

I just noticed a problem in my documentation. I have a file where I have a set of definitions that I am trying to document together, in this form:

```
namespace ABC {
    /**
     * @name ABC
     *
     * Hello.
     *
     * @{
     */

    using Test1 = std::vector<int>;
    using Test2 = std::vector<size_t>;

    /** @}  */
}
```

However, when running doxygen on this file, the documentation for `ABC` and the typedefs inside repeats itself twice. This does not happen if the group is placed outside the namespace in global scope.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

- Doxygen version 1.8.17
- `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`

Comment: Please specify the doxygen version used as well as the settings used (different from the default settings).

Answer (score 2):

In the doxygen version 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19 (I didn't look at earlier versions) the shown problem is present.
In version 1.8.20 and newer the problem is gone.

- solution is to upgrade doxygen to the current version (1.9.1).